# Temporily disable timestamp in Serilog

Tags: c#, wpf, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I'm using the package *Serilog.Sinks.File* I want to disable timestamp just for few messages without creating another instance of LoggerConfiguration for example-

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}").CreateLogger();
```

Output:

```
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] App started
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] Some process1
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] file1
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] file2
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] file3
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] Operation completed.
```

I want:

```
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] App started
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] Some process1
file1
file2
file3
2023-03-10 05:33:24 [INF] Operation completed.
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the way. I created two logger objects with `shared` parameter true.

```
var logFilePath = "logs/log.txt";
var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(logFilePath, outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}", shared: true).CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration;
var FilesLogger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(logFilePath, outputTemplate: "{Message}{NewLine}", shared: true).CreateLogger();
```